# DB2 records count

Tags: db2

I have a simple user registration table that contains e.g. just two columns - event ID and user name who is registered to that event. This table can contain million of records. Now to show how many users registered to certain event I don't wanna execute SQL query Count(*) every time user loads event WEB-page. Instead of that I want to keep events' counts in a separate table and update that count once a new user registered. So I can use a TRIGGER that would update the counts once new record added/updated to the registration table. Is it a good approach? What if 1000 users are registered at the same time and 1000 records updated/created in registration table? Is TRIGGER gonna work correct? What is the best solution to autocalculate counts? Thanks

Comment: You could use a [materialized query table (MQT)](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0509melnyk/).

Comment: Thank you .. that works perfect.. .

Comment: Would you prefer that I add that as an answer to close off the question? Your choice.

Comment: Side note: if you have an index starting with the event id, a simple count should just do an index seek (instant-ish).  An MQT has a refresh rate.  The trigger would require an exclusive lock on the given row, so only one thread could update it at a time (bottleneck)

Comment: yes zedfoxus, please, add it as an answer. Thank you